# Breakpoint and runtime different results?

Tags: c#, .net, web, automation, watin

I am writing a pdf grabber in C# using Watin. For some reason, my code runs ok when I breakpoint a line and then step through manually, but when I let it run, it does the same (first) step twice and stops. Then after some tome it gives me an error that IE is busy.

Here's my code

```
namespace grabber
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IE preglednik = new IE("blabla.com");
            preglednik.WaitForComplete();


            SpanCollection straniceTipke = preglednik.Spans.Filter(Find.ByClass("stranice"));

            Console.WriteLine();
            int x = 1;
            while (x < 46) { 
                preglednik.WaitForComplete();
                DivCollection ukratko = preglednik.Divs.Filter(Find.ByClass("pregled0"));
                foreach (Div dio in ukratko)
                {
                    string imeprezime = dio.Elements[6].ToString();
                    string[] opisIgodine = dio.Elements[7].ToString().Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string opis = opisIgodine[0];
                    string godine = opisIgodine[1];
                    //LINKOVI

                    dio.Elements[1].GetAttributeValue("onclick");
                    string link = dio.Elements[1].GetAttributeValue("onclick");
                    string[] linkovi = link.Split('\'');
                    string[] fajlovi = link.Split('/');


                }
                Console.WriteLine(x + "     - KRAJ");
                x++;
                straniceTipke[x].Links[0].ClickNoWait();
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "first step" - please list that step.  It's never too late to read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve].  Also, make sure what you're doing is really synchronous -- if anything is timing dependent then setting a breakpoint will change that timing.

Comment: And I suggest translating the varnames into english. It makes reading the code easier if you actually understand the meaning of the names.

Comment: Well I'm not an english native speaker, so I do understand what they do.